# Why doesn't the autoincrement field work properly?

Tags: sql-server

Well, first of all I'm using this online editor (that editor needs a browser like Chrome,Safari or Opera): http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete, so maybe it's just a bug of the editor , but I'd find it strange, as it really looks like it's using a real database.

Anyway, I create a table this way in the editor:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Then I try to insert it with something like:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('Lars','Monsen')
```

And it does insert the values in LastName and FirstName but on ID it inserts a NULL, so it even makes the ID field to malfunction as a PRIMARY KEY.

I've checked that problem is with identity as a if I delete the IDENTITY(1,1) then ID field works a primary key field should.

Is there something I'm missing or is it just a bug?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's definitely a bug. I've tested it.

Comment: More interestingly, it works well for Customers database which is an already existing database. so this query `insert into  Customers (CustomerName) values  ('rbt')` auto increments identity by 1 and creates the next primary key value for the new record with all others fields set to null.